# What tense is the verb "data est" in?

Tags: grammar-identification

What is the tense of data est? I feel like it is the perfect passive (he was given), but that would be datus est.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are perfect passives. The difference is in the subject. For passives in the perfect stem (so also pluperfect and future perfect), you use the fourth principal part, and that declines based on the gender and number of its subject. The form of *esse* will conjugate based on the person and number of the subject.

So you'll see *puer datus est*, but *puella data est* and *baculum datum est*. For plurals, then, you'd have *pueri dati sunt*, *puellae datae sunt*, and *bacula data sunt*. That's all third person. You would also see *ego datus/data sum*, *tu datus/data es*, etc.